# Taxonomy filters don't display results - Drupal 7

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I've updated the taxonomy module to the last version, so after doing this I've noticed that clicking on one category or on one tag of my blocks inside the blog area will produce a page without results.

I've already checked if it was a pathauto fault, and it seems work fine and the settings inside there are right. The field in my blog content type concerning tags and categories are already there, and they are linked to the taxonomy vocabularies.

So at the moment I'm alone in the dark, does anyone knows how to help me in order to sort out this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome. It would be difficult I'm afraid to help in the dark too, but I hope we find an end. What do you mean updated the taxonomy module btw?

Comment: Hi Wtower, thanks :)

I've updated the taxonomy module in drupal via drush to the newer version, this version take out the Data Taxonomy submodule (that seems to be vanished from the drupal module's repo) anyway the result that I have so far is the one that I've written, no results even if I've specified every single categories and tags in the blog posts. So at the moment I really don't know how to sort out this thing. Any idea on what I can try to do also to make a debug?

Comment: So ok making some tries again and again with the version control (glad to have it), I've found that this is due to some security updates that I've ran, in the database updates that they made there's an update of the Taxonomy table where it delete the unpublished indexes, so I guess that it is due to it, because after the problem starts to appear again. So I think so that it is due to it.

Comment: Checking the differences between the tables before and after the new taxonomy_index table is bigger than the other. (which is strange because it was needing to be smaller)

Comment: The problem seems to be not due to the db, so it is because of code updates, if I will sort out it, I'll write a solution, if while I'm doing it, someone can give me suggestions should be very cool. Thanks to everyone will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've found the right solution to this issue. I will write down it as who will have the same problem can sort it out.

To solve this problem I was just needing to create again the panel-page that I've used to create the taxonomy pages.

Why I was needing to do it? - It's simple, because when there's a new update if you have any entity that is pointing to a module's variable or whatever about that module and something is obviously changed in its implementation after the update, then this entity is pointing to the old representation of that variable/whatever of that module, so obviously drupal will show you an empty set as a result of a normal query.

I hope that this can help someone on the way in the future.

Have a good day drupalers!!
See ya next time ;)